# does itunes fire events that other processes on the OS can listen for?

Tags: macos, cocoa, itunes

I have an app in mind that I'm considering creating that would involve knowing what song is playing in itunes.

If itunes doesn't fire events, is there a database or some way to programatically get at what is playing in itunes?

Comment: what kind of events you'd like to "monitor" ?

Comment: Raptor, it says what I'm looking for in my question. I'd like to know what song is playing. So, the most important events to monitor would be when a song starts or stops.

Comment: this maybe related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66052/40962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iTunes does send out Distributed notifications. You can get complete track status by observing   **com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo**

```
NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "iTunesNotification:", name: "com.apple.iTunes.playerInfo", object: nil)
func iTunesNotification (notification:NSNotification!) {
    var trackInfo:NSDictionary! = notification.userInfo
    println("Track Info \(trackInfo)")
}
```

Sample output for a track is:

```
Track Info {
    Album = "The Very Best Of Sting & The Police";
    "Album Artist" = "Sting & The Police";
    "Album Rating" = 0;
    "Album Rating Computed" = 1;
    Artist = "Sting & The Police";
    "Artwork Count" = 1;
    Composer = Sting;
    Genre = Rock;
    "Library PersistentID" = 3465537150503037139;
    Location = "file://localhost/Users/GoodSpeed/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/Sting%20&%20The%20Police/The%20Very%20Best%20Of%20Sting%20&%20The%20Police/17%20Roxanne.mp3";
    Name = Roxanne;
    PersistentID = 716102833338382931;
    "Play Count" = 1;
    "Play Date" = "2013-12-28 10:43:24 +0000";
    "Player State" = Playing;
    "Playlist PersistentID" = 5080879747404822807;
    "Rating Computed" = 1;
    "Skip Count" = 0;
    "Store URL" = "itms://itunes.com/link?n=Roxanne&an=Sting%20%26%20The%20Police&pn=The%20Very%20Best%20Of%20Sting%20%26%20The%20Police&cn=Sting";
    "Total Time" = 190458;
    "Track Number" = 17;
    Year = 2002;
}
```